# How to close double include_once in php $div

Tags: php

I am including two files in my index page:

```
$PageData = new Page_Data(); 
$PageData->title ="Welcome to my page";
$div=  "<div class='login-form'>" . include_once "views/navigation.php" . include_once "controllers/login.php" . "</div>";
$PageData->content .=$div;
```

And I get these two errors.

> Warning: include_once(controllers/login.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\kalle_000\Documents\KEA\3rd Semester\3rd
>   Module\Module_8\PHP_new\index.php on line 9
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'controllers/login.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\Users\kalle_000\Documents\KEA\3rd Semester\3rd
>   Module\Module_8\PHP_new\index.php on line 9 test content

What am I doing wrong? All the files are in the right folder where they should be. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You use relative paths. That means, relative to the working directory.  Apparently PHP searches files in a different folder. Btw, you don't need to concat the `include`s. `include` doesn't return a relevant value.

Comment: Where is your index page?

Comment: The code from your includes is not appended to the $div but echoed instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the syntax to this:

```
$PageData = new Page_Data(); 
$PageData->title ="Welcome to my page";
$div=  "<div class='login-form'>";
$div.= include_once ("views/navigation.php");
$div.= include_once ("controllers/login.php");
$div.= "</div>";


$PageData->content .=$div;
```

For some reason, the browser didn't understand the previous syntax, but gets this and now it works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

```
include_once "views/navigation.php" . include_once "controllers/login.php" . "</div>"
```

This is basically evaluated as

```
include_once ("views/navigation.php" . (include_once ("controllers/login.php" . "</div>")))
```

That means first `"controllers/login.php" . "</div>"` is tried to be included, then `views/navigation.php0` (`"views/navigation.php"` + result of the first `include`). That obviously won't work very well.

Further, the included content probably won't be concatenated into `$div` either, but output directly.
You probably want:

```
ob_start();
echo "<div class='login-form'>";
include_once "views/navigation.php";
include_once "controllers/login.php";
echo "</div>";
$div = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: What you say is true, but doesn't answer the question/solve the problem. The problem is that the file cannot be found. How its output would be processed is only a possible next issue, and you probably won't need output buffering to solve it.

Comment: @GolezTrol *"That means first "controllers/login.php" . "</div>" is tried to be included..."* - that's the reason it doesn't include. I'm assuming the `<br>` is eaten by the browser. Half-guessing here though.

Comment: Interesting theory, but it doesn't match the error message. If the `<br>` or `<div>` would be added to the file name *and* be outputted as plain HTML, then you would at least see a new line in the error message. But maybe some magic happens that hides this fact.

Comment: It is certainly part of the problem. The code *cannot* work in its current form. Bringing it into a form that *can* work is first priority, if the paths are still wrong that's a followup question. We obviously can't diagnose his paths from here.

Comment: I think you are right. Interesting thing, though: the code in the question doesn't work for me at all. Without the parentheses, I get "`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`".